# JMeter : Large File Upload in chunks

Tags: file-upload, jmeter

We are trying to test large file upload scenario in JMeter.

When we upload a file with size of 15MB, it will break into 3 chunks (each chunk has 5MB).
I could see separate request in developer tools for each and every chunk going to the server with chunked data. I hope this chunking mechanism is something handled at the client side but not in server.

It would be a great help if anyone helps to achieve the same in JMeter.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Not clear what you are asking or trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic this behaviour using [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler

1. Install HTTP Raw Request sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

   [image]
2. Capture the real request from the browser using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)
3. Copy and paste raw [TCP stream](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowStreamSection.html) into "Request data" input field
4. That's it, now you should be able to replay the request using JMeter exactly as it is. You might need to perform [parameterisation/correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

Check out [The JMeter HTTP Raw Request Sampler - When and How to Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it) article for more detailed information if needed.

Comment: Hi I have tried the same way as mentioned here in the above link "https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it". I have 2 doubts here, 1) If i copy the raw data along with chunk data for 1 request, how it will work for all chunks for a large file since multiple requests going there? 2) I tried with request data file as mentioned in the link. If I use that approach, how can we achieve that point 1 and do the correlation?